# Zend Framework: Redirect from action helper

Tags: zend-framework

That is my Controller Helper:

```
class Application_Controller_Helper_Test extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl('/index/index');
        // ...
    }
```

But have error, which I can't fix:

> Call to a member function `gotoUrl()` on a non-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to redirect from an action helper, you have to retrieve the redirector helper from the helper broker. The following snippet will redirect to `index/index`.

```
$controller = $request->getControllerName();
$action = $request->getActionName();

// Prevent redirection loop
if ($controller.'/'.$action !== 'index/index') {
    $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector');
    $redirector->gotoSimpleAndExit('index', 'index', 'default');
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but can't open index/index: Firefox tell: The page is not redirecting properly

Comment: I think you have a redirection loop. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->_redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');
```

`$this->redirector('targetAction', 'targetController');`