# redirect root url according to locale in Zend

Tags: url, zend-framework, redirect, routes, locale

Working in ZF: Is it possible to change the base or root url on the www.example.com to www.example.com/$language/home, thus depending on the (browser) locale of the users browser?

Example; If a guest manually types www.example.com I would like to change the url automatically to a url with locale: www.example.com/en/home for guests in en_GB region or www.example.fr/home for guests in fr_FR region.

From the root-url I have all the menu-urls and content locale aware. Clicking a link to a menu item in the url the lang is automatically added after the root. The content on the root url is locale aware too using translate, so english for en_GB en french for fr_FR, etc.

Still missing though I would like to have the root url change to locale aware right from the start of the visit to the application if only the root is entered.

I guess something like
   root :to => redirect("/prepayments")
in Rails 3 from what I understand from [this Q&A on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066504/redirect-root-url-to-somewhere-else-in-rails-application)

I have tried and implemented controller action helpers, redirects, etc. etc. for as far as I could find on this forum, but they all don't offer the solution.
A redirect in htaccess is not possible I think since I first need to get the locale from the browser. Since I don't know this the redirect is dynamic and I cannot set a redirect in htaccess.

I woud appreciate any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the next solution on my question with a little help from Florent in [Zend Framework: Redirect from action helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406170/zend-framework-redirect-from-action-helper):

In my Language Plugin I added

```
public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{...some code handling translate...

$url = $request->getRequestUri();

if ($url === '/') {
    $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Redirector');
    $redirector->gotoUrl($lang.'/home');
}
```

The routes I have them in a routes.ini so `$lang.'/home'` is routed to the indexController and indexAction of the Default module.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what version of Zend you're using I am posting this for **Zend 1.1x**. One thing you could do is "catch" the request before it is dispatched, get the `Accept-Language` [header](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales) and based on the user's preferences there set the locale or redirect the user to a URL you like. One way to do this is in the `FrontController`'s `preDispatch()` [method](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html).
  Keep in mind that:

1. You will need to check if all browsers send this through
2. This header string must be parsed careful

Because of the way it is defined:
`Accept-Language    en,bg;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3`

Also users may and often do set language preferences to a foreign language so this header on its own may not be enough.

The best way to do this in a OOP way is to wrap this functionality in a ZendPlugin.
Attach it in your bootstrap:

```
    protected function _initLocaleHandlerControllerPlugin() {
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $plugin = new App_Controller_Plugin_LocaleHandler();
        $frontController->registerPlugin($plugin);
    }
```

Now in this plugin redefine the `preDispatch()` callback:

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request) {
    $acceptLang = $request->getHeader('Accept-Language');
     //Parse string and get language
    //After parsing set the appropriate locale in `Zend_Locale`
    //redirect the user/dispatch the request?
    //THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE:
     $request->setModuleName('home')
             ->setControllerName('registration')
             ->setDispatched(true);
}
```

Zend 1.x doesn't seem to have a built in class for this, Zend 2 does have the ["Zend\Http\Header\AcceptLanguage" class](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Http.Header.AcceptLanguage.html).

Comment: your solution did not do it. However it somehow led me to the solution I posted as answer. Thanks for helping out!